# Download and cache entire web page on ios

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, asihttprequest, nsurlcache

I need to download an entire webPage and store it in app's documents directory and load it from the cache the next time user visits.

No matter how much I search, I always end up with [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest)..!! even though, it works, its very old and deprecated.So I am looking for some alternatives. Another reason I am trying to avoid it is because ....

> It is a completely reimplemented URL loading system, based on very low
>   level constructs (CFNetwork). So as Apple makes improvements to their
>   high level libraries (NSURLConnection, NSCache) ASIHTTP doesn't get
>   those advancements.

Hence, I tried this [sample code from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/URLCache/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008061-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), It gives me a `NSData` of whichever url i feed it. but, when I try to load this `NSData` into `UIWebView` using, `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` method, I need to specify the mimetype as "text/html" , now the images and links in the webpage doesn't load..!

Is there any other way I can use to achieve it..? perhaps using `NSURLCache`..? but how?? 
Is there any other good libraries ou there that i can use or am I stuck with ASIWebPageRequest..?

FYI, I need to download the entire webpage with all js, css etc.

Comment: You can use this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162295/library-for-caching-web-pages-on-iphone

Comment: THis is another tutorial with your problem's solution http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html

Comment: @AhmedZ. Since iOS 5 , `NSURLCache` could store cached content on file system for `http`. The article you linked is a workaround for iOS 4 or lower.

Comment: @BobCromwell .. thanks for identifying that..

Comment: I referred to EVURLCache (https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache) and a nice article here http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/... with some little tweaks, I am able to achieve it..! @Bob Cromwell , thank you for suggesting NSURLCacheStoragePolicy and NSURLCache.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

About an alternative of ASI, [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is much more popular now. If you want to cache your content, you should have a look at `NSURLCacheStoragePolicy` and `NSURLCache`.

Comment: I tried looking into NSURlCache, but am not exactly able to figure out how to achieve what I want with that..! It would be great if you could  explain a bit more.

Comment: I suggest you clone AFNetworking and read a bit the Sample code.